Query to see if user exists without an exception
Is there any way to query to see if a user exists in microsoft graph without an exception being thrown (i will be querying by id). For example i could do the following:
using Azure.Identity;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

public class GraphApiService
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    
    public GraphApiService(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)

    {

        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

    }

    public async Task<User> UserExists(string userId)

    {
        try
        {
           var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Request().GetAsync();
            return true;
        }

        catch (ServiceException ex)

        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error getting user: {ex.Message}");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

but I would much prefer a way that doesn't throw an exception.

What exception are you getting -- are you referring to the credential challenge exception ?  Or are you asking only about handling the case where the user was not found?

in the try block above if the userid doesn't exist it will return a http 404 status code which results in an exception which is spelled out in thier docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp. To bad it doesn't contain a .contain or .exists method.

Seems, you're working with the v4 SDK version. If you're willing to upgrade to v5 (which is a huge impact on an existing code base) you could use a Native Response Object to intercept the chain and prevent the exception. More infos can be found here.

You can query the users endpoint and fitler on the userpricipalname then check the count of users returned eg
             var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Filter("userPrincipalName eq 'user@domain.com'").GetAsync();
            if (users.Count == 0)
            {

            }


thanks. I will give this a try tomorrow morning.
